# Create ssl certificate without admin rights

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to create a https server on my localhost via node.js and doing so requires me to have a ssl certificate which makes sense my one problem is that every resource I've been able to find to create personal ssl certificates for local testing requires administrative privileges. But for my purposes I don't have administrative privileges on the computer I'm testing on. It's a Windows 8 computer. Does anyone know of a way I can get a functioning ssl certificate for testing without admin rights

Comment: try https://letsencrypt.org/ for ssl certificates.

Comment: _“to create personal ssl certificates for local testing require administrative privileges”_ – I can’t see why that would be the case. // Maybe creating the certificate on a different machine, and then simply ex- and importing it could be an option?

Comment: I can't see why that would be the case either but if you look at OpenSSL it requires admin privileges

Comment: @SambhavSharma thanks for the resource but because I'm serving to localhost I don't really have a domain to hook it up to. And if you look at the frq it requires admin privileges  ages to install

Comment: You could generate a self-signed cert with Node.js using this library https://github.com/andris9/pem/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: @oznu that also requires root permissions ( which are the same as admin privileges in windows)